# Creating a treemap, based on count, using R

Tags: r, visualization

I would like to create a tree map based on the count of "names". However, I am not sure how to do so. Seeking you help on this matter.

```
names <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "B", "F", "F", "H")
names <- names %>% as.factor()
ggplot(names, aes(area= names, fill= names) + geom_treemap()
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can find a lot on how to style the solution given by @Fatih Aslan [here](https://r-charts.com/part-whole/treemapify/)

Answer (score 0):

```
names <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "B", "F", "F", "H")
names <- data.frame(names)

names <- names %>% 
          count(names)

  ggplot(names, aes(area= n, fill= names)) + geom_treemap()
```